# Stopping Visual Studio 2013 from moving my cursor around when editing HTML classes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting really frustrated by a feature that's seemingly been introduced in Visual Studio 2013. I have a piece of HTML like this:

`<div class="test"></div>`

If I move my cursor to alongside `test` so that I can add another class to the tag, which *should* result in this:

`<div class="newclass test"></div>`

...the moment that I press the `SPACE` key after typing `newclass`, Visual Studio automatically moves my cursor to outside the attribute and adds the space there instead, leaving me with:

`<div class="newclasstest" ></div>`

I've trawled through the text editor settings and disabled every auto-complete option or similar I can find. It's really messing with my workflow as one of my projects is very heavy on multiple classes so it's a constant hurdle.

Comment: Any extensions installed? It works for me just fine.. (Visual Studio 2013 update 1), or any extensions I might be running that fix this could be: Resharper and WebEssentials.

Comment: No extensions, I can take a look at those though. I'll use anything to stop this annoyance, heh.

Comment: In your last example did you mean to type <div class="newclass" test ></div> ?

Answer (score 3):

The option to disable this is **Insert attribute value quotes** in Options > Text Editor > HTML > Advanced.

Unfortunately, this leaves you without the long-standing useful feature of getting attribute value quotes automatically inserted.

Your other choice is to hit ESC before hitting space. It seems like this is just going to have to be a reflex behavior Microsoft is forcing us to learn.

One quirk to this behavior is that if there is a space somewhere in front of your cursor, it will not jump outside the quotes. If you have:

```
<div class="newclass test"></div>
```

you can safely add *anotherclass* without it leaping out.

```
<div class="anotherclass newclass test"></div>
```

and now you can add *onemoreclass* anywhere behind *test* and it won't jump out.

```
<div class="anotherclass newclass onemoreclass test"></div>
```

However, since you'll need to hit ESC Space in the extremely common situation of adding two classes one after the other, you'll probably have smacking ESC ingrained in you and will be hitting it everytime regardless.